# 21124-hw2.y: conflicts: 148 shift/reduce, 1 reduce/reduce

Tags: bison, yacc

What is wrong in this bison file?

21124-hw2.y: conflicts: 148 shift/reduce, 1 reduce/reduce
The error is this. Where it is ambiguous??
this bison file connect with flex file these all tokens created in flex as well.
İn this code i didnt write include part and main part of that. As you can see in the comment the problem is ambuguity. And i give the priority of these parts but it didnt work.

```
        %token tFOR tIN tIF tFUNCTION tSEMICOLON tLPAR tLBRKT tSTAR tPLUS tLBRACE tLT tCOLON tINT tREAL tSTRING tWHILE tVAR tELSE tEQCHECK tCOMMA tRPAR tRBRKT tRBRACE tGT tEQ tMINUS tNOT tIDENT  
// these are tokens which i getting in flex
        %left '+' '-' '!'
        %left '*' "=="
        %left '<' '>'
        %left ';'
        %left '='
        %left '(' ')'
        %left '{' '}'
        %left '[' ']'
        %left ',' ':'
       // these re the prirotiries
        %%
        // down below all thing grammer part.
        prog : statementList 
        ;
        statementList : statementList statement
                    | statementList ';' statement
                | statement
        ;
        statement : assign | if | expr | statementBlock
              | while | for | functionCall | functionDeclaration
        ;
        assign : tIDENT '=' expr
               | tVAR tIDENT '=' expr
        ;
        if : ifPart elsePart
        ;
        ifPart : tIF '(' expr ')' statementBlock
        ;
        elsePart :  tELSE statementBlock
             |
        ; 
        while : tWHILE '(' expr ')' statementBlock
        ;
        for : tFOR '(' tIDENT tIN expr ')' statementBlock
            | tFOR '(' tVAR tIDENT tIN expr ')' statementBlock
        ;
        functionDeclaration : tFUNCTION tIDENT '(' exprList ')' statementBlock
                      | tFUNCTION tIDENT '(' ')' statementBlock
        ;
        statementBlock: '{' statementList '}'
        ;
        functionCall : tIDENT '(' exprList ')'
                   | tIDENT '(' ')'
        ;
        // i think the problem is there
        expr : tIDENT | tREAL | tINT | tSTRING |
             | '[' ']' | '[' exprList ']'
             | '{' '}' | '{' propertyList '}'   
             | '!' expr | expr '+' expr | expr '-' expr
             | expr '*' expr | expr "==" expr
             | expr '<' expr | expr '>' expr
//if there is the expr between '*' star should havpriority 
        ;
        exprList : expr | exprList ',' expr
        ;
        propertyList : tIDENT ':' expr 
                     | propertyList ',' tIDENT ':' expr
        ;
        // this down below is  main it say grammaticly correct or not?(i didnt wrote that part)
        %%
```

Comment: The [dangling else](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else) is always ambiguous.

Comment: @AntoineL: Not in this case. The grammar only allows delimited statement blocks in compound statements, so you have to write `if ( cond ) { if (cond) ...`, and that is unambiguous because there is no dangle.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here, at the end of the first quoted line:

```
expr : tIDENT | tREAL | tINT | tSTRING |
     | '[' ']' | '[' exprList ']'
```

The duplicated <kbd>|</kbd> effectively creates the rule:

```
expr : %empty
```

which immediately leads to a huge number of conflicts, particularly since you allow semicolons to be optional:

```
statementList : statementList statement
              | statementList ';' statement
              | statement
```

That error (and a number of other warnings you might want to take into account) would have been indicated immediately if you had asked bison to produce warnings:

```
bison -Wall ...
```

Comment: tIDENT | tREAL | tINT | tSTRING      When i delete | after tSTRING it fixed. You said like that thank you!  @rici